# Wordpress on Azure Error: Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: wordpress, azure, cors

I'm facing this error ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3ALl.png)) at this page https://anthonytd.com/171/2020-jan-products-roundup/

What I have tried

- Enabled CORS in azure web app
- Enabled Header configs in web.config

**Resources**

[Azure Web app config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvCG4.png)

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress: http://anthonytd.azurewebsites.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirect requests from default Azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" /> 
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^anthonytd\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.anthonytd\.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://anthonytd.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: The status of the response header is 204.


Something like this (id |  (failed) 204 | xhr),
(error_204?a=logerror... | (failed) | xhr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem and solution
Problem: Default embed (pasted for Product Hunt links) of Wordpress doesn't work with Product Hunt Embed
Solution: I have to add Custom HTML myself